# Is a device Unlock Code required when changing providers?

Tags: sim-unlocking

So... I just switched from AT&T to Cricket Wireless. They gave me a new SIM, and AT&T gave me an Unlock Code. I have an Android Samsung Galaxy Skyrocket S2.

I use Cricket Wireless.

I put in the new SIM, and was never prompted for a Code. I was able to get hooked up to the Cricket network and make calls just fine.

Am I good to go? Or will I be screwed if I don't get my Unlock Code entered?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Android, actually, since SIM-locking is common for any cellphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're good for now, but don't lose that unlock code!

Cricket is now owned by AT&T, and you can use either an unlocked GSM phone or a locked-to-AT&T or locked to Cricket GSM phone on Cricket. But if you should ever need to use that Galaxy S II Skyrocket SGH-i727 on (for example) T-Mobile, you'll need the unlock code!

To unlock a Samsung Galaxy phone, you just need to put a non-AT&T, non-Cricket SIM card in it, and then power-on the phone. It should prompt you for the unlock code. If you don't have a non-AT&T, non-Cricket SIM card, then just visit a T-Mobile store, and let them put one of theirs in it.

AT&T has unlocking instructions here:
http://www.att.com/media/att/2014/support/pdf/ATTMobilityDeviceUnlockCodeInstructions.pdf

Comment: Does the unlock code expire? Let's say I travel abroad with the phone after 3 years and need to temporarily use a local provider. Will the code work at that time?

Answer (score 0):

You only need an unlock code if your phone was SIM-locked to start with. Not all phones are, and if you didn't get the phone from the carrier it definitely wasn't.

Comment: I did get the phone from the carrier.

Comment: Even then, it's not necessarily locked. If it were, it wouldn't be working at all, so don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone is running fine, then don't worry about it.  It's possible that they unlocked your phone over-the-air... Sounds weird, but some companies do it with certain phones (for example, Sprint pushes out unlock codes over-the-air).

Did you buy your phone outright from the carrier (the full price), or did you sign a contract?

Comment: 2 year contract with AT&T came, paid for the phone from them for a discount